# Wordpress Plugin on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm actually trying to setup a wordpress environment on App Engine standard. I'm facing a problem with a Wordpress plugin, Visual Composer : https://wordpress.org/plugins/visualcomposer/.

It looks like wp-content directory is read-only, as mentionned in Google's docs. Therefore visual composer is trying to write in, and I get this error 'mkdir(), Enable to write to wp-content - read-only directory'. Any others persons are experimenting this issue ? Is there a way to put wp-content in writable mode ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AppEngine Standard doesn't allow writing to local disk:

> In the Google App Engine PHP 5 Standard Environment, the local
> filesystem that your application is deployed to is not writeable. This
> behavior ensures the security and scalability of your application.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage

If your application (or plugin) needs access to the local filesystem, AppEngine Standard is not the way to go.
Nevertheless, AppEngine Flexible mode does, so you can try Flexible mode.